# wpdb->get row Select (quite complex) Query don't work

Tags: database, wordpress, select

Please, someone could tell me what is the mistake in this database query? It doesn't want to work for something :S

This is the full function:

```
function foglaltautok(){

    global $wpdb;

    $carname     = $_POST['car-model'];
    $pickupdate  = $_POST['pick-up-date'];
    $dropoffdate = $_POST['drop-off-date'];
    $days        = (strtotime($dropoffdate) - strtotime($pickupdate)) / (60 * 60 * 24)+1;

    $foglaltvagynem = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT carmodel 
        FROM autofoglalt 
        WHERE carmodel = $carname 
            && ($pickupdate BETWEEN  pickupdate AND  dropoffdate 
            OR $dropoffdate BETWEEN  pickupdate AND  dropoffdate 
            OR pickupdate   BETWEEN $pickupdate AND $dropoffdate 
            OR dropoffdate  BETWEEN $pickupdate AND $dropoffdate)"); 

    if(null!==$foglaltvagynem) {
        echo 'error';   
    }
    else 
        if(null === $foglaltvagynem) {
            $wpdb->insert('autofoglalt', array(
                'carmodel'    => $carname,
                'pickupdate'  => $pickupdate,
                'dropoffdate' => $dropoffdate,
                'napok'       => $days
            ));
        }

    die();
}
```

**And this part doesn't work** :S :

```
$foglaltvagynem = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT carmodel 
    FROM autofoglalt 
    WHERE carmodel = $carname 
    && ($pickupdate     BETWEEN  pickupdate AND  dropoffdate 
        OR $dropoffdate BETWEEN  pickupdate AND  dropoffdate 
        OR pickupdate   BETWEEN $pickupdate AND $dropoffdate 
        OR dropoffdate  BETWEEN $pickupdate AND $dropoffdate)"
    );
```

I wrote this code to a Car Rental page, and with this Query I want to know, that the selected CAR is FREE or RESERVED -from selected pickupdate -to selected dropoffdate..- So it's already in the database, or not? :)

Comment: you can get the error message of your query using $wpdb->last_error

Comment: share your database structure over here please

Comment: Table name: `autofoglalt`

5 columns:
1st the row ID-s (it doesn't matter..)) -----int----primary

2.: carmodel ---- varchar-----NULL
3.: pickupdate----- date-----NULL
4.: dropoffdate-----date------NULL
5.: napok (days... this is the period number from pickupdate to dropoffdate)-----int-----NULL

Comment: (I wanted to upload picture about database table, but i didn't find any option here for the upload)